# Communicating with XBoard (chess engine) (C++/C)

Tags: c++, c, io, chess

I was just toying around with making a basic chess engine. I was able to get a lot of advice from http://web.archive.org/web/20070704121716/http://www.brucemo.com/compchess/programming/alphabeta.htm, but the real site is down and not all the pages are archived. (Anyone know where to find a full version of Bruce's site?)

But now to the real question: how do I communicate with XBoard? I understand it is via stdin and stdout, but I've been having problems in code. Basically, to get started, I just want to

1. receive input from XBoard and print it to the console/screen
2. Give a move of hard-coded input to XBoard and have it make the move
3. program utility functions and have a random chess ai which chooses random moves.

After that, I can start implementing real things like alpha-beta searching.

I am stuck on the first two things right now. Here is some code I have tried to write/borrowed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STR_BUFF 256

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char input[STR_BUFF];
    char output[STR_BUFF];
    while(true){
        fflush(stdout);
        // read input
        if (!fgets(input, STR_BUFF, stdin)){
            printf("terminated");
            return 0;;
        }

        printf("%s", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am just getting back into C after about 6 months break and this is the first project that I have used stdin/stdout pipelines to communicate with another program (minus a few basic programs) so I would appreciate any help and any explanations. I know programming a chess engine is a herculean task, but I have already programmed the rules of chess before and what I can find of Bruce's site is absolutely amazing.

Comment: May I suggest you look at http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/ as a replacement for Bruce Moreland's site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it almost right: get a command from XBoard with `fgets`, then report a move with `printf` and `fflush`. (One thing is wrong, though: you don't need to 'print the command to the console/screen'; you are not communicating with the console/screen; you only read commands from XBoard and send moves back to XBoard).

Probably, it would be easier to start with some existing code. Try to read sources for [GNU Chess](http://www.gnu.org/software/chess/chess.html). Or download sources for any [other chess engine](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/lastupdates.htm), supporting XBoard protocol.

And here is other question with lots of information on chess engine programming: "[What are some good resources for writing a chess engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/494721/1009831)".

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're looking for pipe(), included in unistd.h. Take a look at [Can popen() make bidirectional pipes like pipe() + fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884103/can-popen-make-bidirectional-pipes-like-pipe-fork) for notes on implementation.

Comment: Yes, I also used pipe(). This is also how XBoard is implemented.