# What kind of resources are available for building a 2  player chess games interface?

Tags: javascript, html, chess

I want to create a 2 player chess game. What HTML and JS resources are available for creating a chess board with ability to move the pieces? (note: I dont want a chess engine)

Also once I setup the chess board in browser how should I make the moves consistent with another person who has opened the same webpage in browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some good resources for writing a chess engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494721/what-are-some-good-resources-for-writing-a-chess-engine)

Comment: Not a dupe, that question is about AI for chess, this one's about interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jQuery AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for communicating the moves between players (and a server) in real-time.

For the end-user interactivity, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) (official extension of jQuery).  Particularly, the [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert) and/or [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid) controls.

*(see the linked demos)*

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the online chess application I am developing, the UI is written in `HTML` & `javascript (jQuery/knockout.js)` and the backend is written in Java running on Jetty 8 server.
I am making use of native websockets for communication. The application is hosted at `http://www.chesshunt.com`

Although the chess rules are all written at server side, but you can still see the board implementations in `Javascript`.